# How to export new discord.js clients from another script

Tags: javascript, express, discord, discord.js, hosting

My index.js file:

```
app.get("/bots/host", auth, async (req, res) => {
    const client = require("./bot")
    client.login(data.token)
    client.on('ready', () => {
        console.log("Bot ready from the panel")
    })
})
```

My bot.js file:

```
const client = new Discord.Client()

client.on('ready', () => {
   console.log(client.user.username)
})
module.exports = client
```

All i want is to get client and make a new one like this `const client = new require("./bot")`

Comment: 2 things: Why are you putting the new keyword before require?; What is happening instead?

Answer (score 2):

You are already exporting an instance of a [`Client`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client). You can't declare a *new instance of an instance*. I'd recommend to take a look basic JavaScript [Classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) and [Modules](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html).
Besides you usually want to use [`require()`](https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/getting-started/what-is-require/) at the very top of your file. Also there is no reason to first define a `on("ready", ...)` and then override it in the other file. `on` is a regular property and gets exported with the client.

To give a working sample:

*bot.js*:

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.once("ready", () => {
  console.log(`from bot.js: ${client.user.username}`);
});

client.login("your-token");

module.exports = client;
```

*index.js*:

```
const client = require("./bot");

console.log(`from index.js: ${client.token}`);
```

I porpusely `console.log()`ed `client.token` in *index.js* hence, other than e.g. `client.user`, this is a property that does not have to be fetched explicitly.